# How to tune my prediction with binary dataset using Support Vector Machine?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, machine-learning, svm

So I have this dataset (1000 column by 1000 row) which has two classes, zero or one,  where I applied the code below and it gave me a prediction rate of 58% I want to tune it but I am really confused between the different classes and how to select their parameters with this type of data, so I wish if I get some guideline here.

```
#here I am importing the libraries that I need for this situation
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm

#reading the data
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
x = data.loc[:, 'D_0':'D_1023']
y = data['Class']
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
model.fit(x,y)
model.score(x,y)
predictions = model.predict(test)
pd.DataFrame(predictions,
             columns=['PredictedScore']).to_csv('prediction.csv')
```

[Sample of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf0LU.png)

Comment: Read the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html)

Comment: @leoschet I read them but they don't specify which one is suitable for small amount of data (1000 for two classes in my case) and there language I find it a bit hard

Answer (score 0):

The parameters really depend upon the data, so there is no general guideline. However, at least trying the "rbf" kernel is worth the effort I think. Also, I would first start by changing the C parameter, as that usually has the largest effect. But again, it depends on the data a lot.

Comment: Actually, "rbf" kernel improves with more data. Another interesting thing would be to try the "poly" kernel and trying different degrees starting from 3. For smaller datasets, maybe polynomial kernels would be better.